# `sudo` with command substitution

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I'm working with a remote machine that requires `sudo` for most `docker` commands. I often have to perform multiple repetitive commands to stop docker containers, etc: `sudo docker stop <container_name>`.

Normally, I'd use `docker stop $(docker ps -q)` to stop all the results of `docker ps -q`, but simply prefixing this with sudo doesn't do what I'm after: `sudo docker stop $(docker ps -q)` results in a permission denied error.

Is there a way to pipe this through sudo so that I don't have to stop everything individually?

Comment: The reason for that is Docker run as a daemon and they are mostly run with privileges. If you need to do that as a different user; you need give that user privileges to do so. Docker kindly documented that https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need to specify sudo` in the inner command. So the following should work:

```
sudo docker stop $(sudo docker ps -q)
```

Answer (score 0):

xargs also should work:

```
$ sudo docker ps -q | xargs sudo docker stop
```